# How to print out NSDictionary in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, terminal

How can I print value of an NSDictionary in Swift?

```
let gr2 : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
        gr2.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result2, error) -> Void in
```

And here is the **Console** output:

```
(lldb) po result2
(instance_type = Builtin.RawPointer = 0x145b6340 -> 0x3529fbc0 (void *)0x3529fbd4: __NSCFDictionary)
 {
  instance_type = 0x145b6340 -> 0x3529fbc0 (void *)0x3529fbd4: __NSCFDictionary
}
```

But here I got some negligible output. I want to see keys and values.

Comment: @Rob Can you explain me lldb and post answer for this question?

Comment: János, this is curious, because when I set a breakpoint inside `startWithCompletionHandler` that I called from Swift and do `po result2`, I see a proper dictionary. I'm unable to reproduce the behavior you describe. I'm using Xcode 6.3. What version of Xcode are you using? I do remember seeing strange `po` results in prior versions of Xcode.

Comment: I am using Version 6.2 (6C131e), I might need to update it

Comment: FYI, note that 6.3 uses Swift 1.2 with a few minor (and while good, still annoying) syntactic differences; see https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=22 and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1). You probably want to update, anyway, but just a heads up.

Comment: you are right, now in Xcode 6.3 array and dictionary is able to print out in console :D